# Android app crashes at activity when trying to open the database connection to pass to webview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-webview, android-sqlite

I am trying to develop an app which performs a query on database according to spinner value and then pass it on to the next intent in webview. For some reason it keeps crashing on that activity. here is my code:

```
//import android.R;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    public class Monthly extends Activity{

        DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter;
        private Spinner emonth;
        private Spinner eyear;
        private Button submit;
        private double price1, price2, price3, price4, price5, price6, price7;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_monthly);

            emonth = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.month, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            emonth.setAdapter(adapter); 

            eyear = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.years, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            eyear.setAdapter(adapter2);

            submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            submit.setOnClickListener(submitOnClickListener);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


        OnClickListener submitOnClickListener =
                 new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(v.getId()==R.id.button1)
              {

               String month=emonth.getSelectedItem().toString();
               String year=eyear.getSelectedItem().toString();

               dbAdapter.open();
               Cursor price1=dbAdapter.queryFoodMonth(month, year);

               Cursor price2=dbAdapter.queryClothingMonth(month, year);

               Cursor price3=dbAdapter.queryElectronicsMonth(month, year);

               Cursor price4=dbAdapter.queryUtilityMonth(month, year);

               Cursor price5=dbAdapter.queryEntertainmentMonth(month, year);

               Cursor price6=dbAdapter.queryFuelMonth(month, year);

               Cursor price7=dbAdapter.queryOtherMonth(month, year);
               dbAdapter.close();

                         Intent intent = new Intent(Monthly.this,WebChart.class);

                            intent.putExtra("PRICE1", getNum(price1));
                            intent.putExtra("PRICE2", getNum(price2));
                            intent.putExtra("PRICE3", getNum(price3));
                            intent.putExtra("PRICE4", getNum(price4));
                            intent.putExtra("PRICE5", getNum(price5));
                            intent.putExtra("PRICE6", getNum(price6));
                            intent.putExtra("PRICE7", getNum(price7));
                            startActivity(intent);

                     }
        }    
                        };

                       private double getNum(Cursor price){

                           double num = 0.0;
                           String stringNum = price.toString();
                             if(!stringNum.equals("")){
                              num = Integer.valueOf(stringNum);
                             }

                             return (num);
                       }

        }
```

This is the code in the Database Adapter that gives the cursor.

```
public Cursor queryFoodMonth(String month,String year)
 {
     Cursor c1 = database.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(price) FROM items where month=  \" "+month+" \" AND year=  \" "+year+"  \" AND category =  \"Food\";",null);

        if (c1 !=null) {
            c1.moveToFirst();
        }

        return c1;

 }

 public Cursor queryClothingMonth(String month,String year)
 {
     Cursor c2 = database.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(price) FROM items where month=  \" "+month+" \" AND year=  \" "+year+"  \" AND category =  \"Clothing\";",null);

        if (c2 !=null) {
            c2.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c2;
 }

 public Cursor queryElectronicsMonth(String month,String year)
 {
     Cursor c3 = database.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(price) FROM items where month=  \" "+month+" \" AND year=  \" "+year+"  \" AND category =  \"Electronics\";",null);

        if (c3 !=null) {
            c3.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c3;
 }

 public Cursor queryUtilityMonth(String month,String year)
 {
     Cursor c4 = database.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(price) FROM items where month=  \" "+month+" \" AND year=  \" "+year+"  \" AND category =  \"Utility\";",null);

        if (c4 !=null) {
            c4.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c4;
 }

 public Cursor queryEntertainmentMonth(String month,String year)
 {
     Cursor c5 = database.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(price) FROM items where month=  \" "+month+" \" AND year=  \" "+year+"  \" AND category =  \"Entertainment\";",null);

        if (c5 !=null) {
            c5.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c5;
 }

 public Cursor queryFuelMonth(String month,String year)
 {
     Cursor c6 = database.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(price) FROM items where month=  \" "+month+" \" AND year=  \" "+year+"  \" AND category =  \"Fuel\";",null);

        if (c6 !=null) {
            c6.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c6;
 }

 public Cursor queryOtherMonth(String month,String year)
 {
     Cursor c7 = database.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(price) FROM items where month=  \" "+month+" \" AND year=  \" "+year+"  \" AND category =  \"Other\";",null);

        if (c7 !=null) {
            c7.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c7;
 }
```

And this the logcat error report:

```
12-03 17:31:25.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1993): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 17:31:25.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1993): Process: com.csj.monthlybudg, PID: 1993
12-03 17:31:25.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1993): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 17:31:25.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1993):     at com.csj.monthlybudg.Monthly$1.onClick(Monthly.java:78)
12-03 17:31:25.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1993):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
12-03 17:31:25.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1993):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
12-03 17:31:25.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1993):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-03 17:31:25.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1993):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-03 17:31:25.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1993):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-03 17:31:25.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1993):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12-03 17:31:25.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1993):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 17:31:25.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1993):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-03 17:31:25.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1993):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-03 17:31:25.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1993):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-03 17:31:25.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1993):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can see that the error is at line 78 which while opening the database connection but i don't understand what is wrong. Any help would much appreciated and if you find my question naive please don't be harsh I am new to android and java. 
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do something like `dbAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter()` before calling `dbAdapter.open();`

Null pointer exceptions usually occur when you try to use a reference(`dbAdapter` in this case) that points to nothing in the memory, i.e. you haven't yet create anything for the reference to point to.

Comment: I am already specifying that in the beginning right after i start my class..

DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter;

Comment: @JamieRodhes something like dbAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter()?

Comment: I just did that and it throws that error at line 80 which is now the same dbAdapter.open();

Comment: Yeah it extends the SQLiteOpenHelper I've performed other querries like inserting and retrieving data from the database.

Comment: post your DatabaseAdapter class as well

Comment: the app still crashes but its for something else. I'll take sometime and try to figure out.

Comment: I am having problems after i changed it can you help me out if I edit the above question instead of posting a new one.